Latest revyos TH1520 Linux kernel doesn't work on LicheePI 4a
Heyaw,
We have a LicheePi4a board. We are using a linux kernel version that is around 8 months old (when we started the project more or less) which currently works.
Now we tried to update the linux kernel to its latest version f6b3a51 but it doesn't run (no tux or blinking hyphen, fan not working).
What I am trying: using binary search, I am trying to find the commit which introduces the bug, having to compile and test each commit (which is a pain) on the board. I think I am close to the commit but I was wondering if anyone was having the same issue or know a better way to debug this.
Thank you!

What do the console logs say?

I cannot see the kernel logs because the commits that don't work fail to boot the kernel. I also considered using GDB or dmesg, but at best, the system hangs right after the Tux logo appears.

Have you narrowed down the problematic commits ?

Hi @droptop thank you for your questions. Yes, I used binary search on git log until I found 2 commits which I think are part of the issue.
The first was introducing dtbs filename changes, which I referenced correctly and now the latest version is booting the kernel although it gets hanged up (doesn't load the system). I tried changing some defconfig parameters which where troublesome in other commits, but it didn't work out.

Could you point to those commits? What logs does the bootloader (I suppose you're using U-Boot) produce?

Sorry for the late answer, the bootloader is not producing any logs (at least not through the display, we are trying to get the early boot and kernel logs through UART). We also tried using printk on main.c but nothing is shown when booting up.
The troublesome commits are sha 6a61ffb0b and e17ac7bab
